# DESCARGAR PDF GENERADO CON iTEXT SPRING BOOT WEB APP

Tags: java, pdf, spring-boot, itext

Estoy trabajando en una web app con spring boot y necesito generar un reporte en PDF para lo cual utilice iText. El reporte ya funciona y queda como quiero, solo que el archivo que se genera queda guardado en el server. Mi intención es que se abra automáticamente en otra ventana del navegador o por lo menos que ofrezca la opción de descargarlo al usuario. Les agradecería me ayuden. Les copio el código actual para generar el PDF.

```
public class ReciboPdf {

public void reciboPagos(Pago pago) throws Exception {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    Calendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendario.setTime(pago.getFechaPago());
    String mes = FechaUtil.obtenerNombreMes(calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    String funcionalidad = "";
    if (pago.getFuncionalidad() != null) {
        funcionalidad = pago.getFuncionalidad().getTitulo();
    }

    String pagoA = "";
    if (pago.getRecurso() != null) {
        pagoA = pago.getRecurso().getNombre();
    }

    Font fuenteTitulo = new Font();
    fuenteTitulo.setSize(20);

    Font negrita = new Font();
    negrita.setStyle(Font.BOLD);

    Image logoEncabezado = Image.getInstance("classpath:static/img/membrete.png");

    logoEncabezado.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    logoEncabezado.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4);
    logoEncabezado.setAbsolutePosition(0f, 0f);

    Chunk titulo = new Chunk("RECIBO");
    titulo.setUnderline(2f, -2f);

    titulo.setFont(fuenteTitulo);

    Chunk fecha = new Chunk(
            "Buenos Aires, " + calendario.get(Calendar.DATE) + " de " + mes + " de " + calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    Paragraph parrafo = new Paragraph("Recibi de LA EMPRESA la cantidad de pesos $" + pago.getImporte()
            + " en concepto de pago por la funcionalidad " + funcionalidad + " correspondiente al proyecto "
            + pago.getProyecto().getTitulo());

    parrafo.setLeading(5.0f, 1.0f);

    Chunk firma = new Chunk("_____________________________________");

    Chunk nombre = new Chunk(pagoA);
    nombre.setFont(negrita);

    PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(1);

    PdfPCell celda0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
    PdfPCell celda1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(titulo));
    PdfPCell celda2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(fecha));
    PdfPCell celda3 = new PdfPCell(parrafo);
    PdfPCell celda4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(firma));
    PdfPCell celda5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(nombre));

    tabla.addCell(celda0);
    tabla.addCell(celda1);
    tabla.addCell(celda2);
    tabla.addCell(celda3);
    tabla.addCell(celda4);
    tabla.addCell(celda5);

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("recibo_" + pago.getId() + ".pdf"));
    document.open();
    document.add(logoEncabezado);
    document.add(tabla);
    document.close();

}
}
```

Lo testee unicamente en entorno local. No lo he cargado en ningun hosting. Busque soluciones pero no las encontre por el momento, supongo que la solucion debe venir al momento de hacer el document.close() y en PdfWriter.getInstance.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @lisi1986, Podrías mencionar cual tecnología estas utilizando para la web, y si el back-end serán servicios REST o estas trabajando con un solo proyecto que contiene todo el código.

Comment: Roberto, estoy utilizando Sping MVC con Thymeleaf, no estoy utilizando REST, el proyecto contiene todo el codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El principal problema que tienes es que no estas diferenciando a donde están ocurriendo los eventos, debes de tener en cuenta que Spring MVC se ejecuta del lado del servidor por lo que si guardas un archivo `new FileOutputStream("recibo_" + pago.getId() + ".pdf")` se guardara en el servidor no en la computadora del cliente, al contrario de la mayoría de framework de JavaScript que corre del lado del cliente por lo que las acciones si son en la maquina que carga la web, lo que debes hacer en lugar de guardar el pdf lo debes convertir a un `ByteArrayOutputStream` que tendrás en memoria y luego transferidlo al lado del cliente, te dejo un ejemplo rápido de cómo hacerlo:

Primero creamos una clase para simular tu reporte pero que tendrá el cambio para escribir en memoria el archivo:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class PdfGenerator {

    public ByteArrayOutputStream getPDF() {

        // Creamos la instancia de memoria en la que se escribirá el archivo temporalmente
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            Calendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar();
            String mes = "Febrero";
            String funcionalidad = "Prueba";
            String pagoA = "pagoA";
            Font fuenteTitulo = new Font();
            fuenteTitulo.setSize(20);

            Font negrita = new Font();
            negrita.setStyle(Font.BOLD);


            Chunk titulo = new Chunk("RECIBO");
            titulo.setUnderline(2f, -2f);

            titulo.setFont(fuenteTitulo);

            Chunk fecha = new Chunk(
                    "Buenos Aires, " + calendario.get(Calendar.DATE) + " de " + mes + " de " + calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR));

            Paragraph parrafo = new Paragraph("Recibi de LA EMPRESA la cantidad de pesos $" + "10000"
                    + " en concepto de pago por la funcionalidad " + funcionalidad + " correspondiente al proyecto "
                    + "Proyecto Prueba");

            parrafo.setLeading(5.0f, 1.0f);

            Chunk firma = new Chunk("_____________________________________");

            Chunk nombre = new Chunk(pagoA);
            nombre.setFont(negrita);

            PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(1);

            PdfPCell celda0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
            PdfPCell celda1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(titulo));
            PdfPCell celda2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(fecha));
            PdfPCell celda3 = new PdfPCell(parrafo);
            PdfPCell celda4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(firma));
            PdfPCell celda5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(nombre));

            tabla.addCell(celda0);
            tabla.addCell(celda1);
            tabla.addCell(celda2);
            tabla.addCell(celda3);
            tabla.addCell(celda4);
            tabla.addCell(celda5);

            // Asignamos la variable ByteArrayOutputStream bos donde se escribirá el documento
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, bos);
            document.open();
            document.add(tabla);
            document.close();
            // Retornamos la variable al finalizar
            return bos;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Ahora creamos un controlador que asigne el archivo al response para ser descargado:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
public class FileDownloadController {

    @GetMapping("/download")
    public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PdfGenerator generator = new PdfGenerator();
        byte[] pdfReport = generator.getPDF().toByteArray();

        String mimeType =  "application/pdf";
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", "reporte.pdf"));

        response.setContentLength(pdfReport.length);

        ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( pdfReport);

        FileCopyUtils.copy(inStream, response.getOutputStream());
    }

}
```

Por ultimo creamos un archivo html que ejecutara la descarga:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Spring MVC</title></head>
<body>
<div class="form-container">
    <h1>Ejemplo de Descarga</h1>

    Clic en el link para descarga archivo.<br/><br/>

    <a href="/download">Descargar archivo</a>
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Roberto, muchisimas gracias!!! funciona a la perfeccion. Me queda una consulta, este método para generar el PDF esta dentro de otro método que primero persiste la entidad, luego genera el PDF y finalmente redirecciona al listado de entidades. Con este cambio que hice al usar el HttpServletResponse esta omitiendo la redireccion y queda en la vista donde cargo los datos de la entidad, como deberia hacer para volver a redireccionar? intente con         `response.sendRedirect("/pago/listado/" + pago.getProyecto().getId());` pero me da error porque ya está comiteado el objeto HttpServletResponse.

Comment: Por ultimo, como deberia hacer si quiero que el PDF generado lo abra en otra pestaña del navegador con su previsualizador en vez de descargarlo?

Comment: Como se puede hacer que el pdf se descargue de esta forma pero en vez de generar el archivo desde codigo java convierta una vista html en pdf?